# How should i enable the checkbox using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

when I click the checkbox,it should be enabled until i click the checkbox for the next time even when the application is closed or I am in the another html Page.Once the checkbox is clicked again it should be disabled.

Comment: You mean you want to store the checkbox state between pages? Can you write it to something using phonegap's storage API then load the value back and update the checkbox when you next load that page?

Comment: Why not set a cookie with the enabled/disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is **HTML 5 local storage**.  I believe this is supported in IE 8+ and all other major browsers.  Here is an example of how you would do it:

```
//Runs once the DOM is ready
$(function() {
    //Store the check box element in a variable
    var checkbox = $("#elementID");
    //The change event gets triggered every time the check box element is clicked
    checkbox.change(function() {
        //Set the checkbox value in local storage
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", checkbox.prop("checked"));
    });
    var checkValue = localStorage.getItem("checkboxValue");
    //Since localStorage returns a string, you must catch it
    //and then check or uncheck the box
    if(checkValue === "true") {
        //Check the box
        checkbox.prop("checked", true)
    }
    else {
        //Uncheck the box
        checkbox.prop("checked", false)
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work with jQuery versions > 1.6.  If you are using a version of jQuery < 1.6, then replace the "prop" method with "attr"